# Strip img src from posted screenshot data php

Tags: php, regex, base64, screenshot

Looking for some regex based help! Have already searched the site and not found any solutions that are yet applicable for my case.

I have a form that is shown to users, one of the text areas is a pasting area for a screenshot. Currently this screenshot data is entered into a database but as this is starting to make the database quite large I have decided to create an individual image for each of the pasted screenshots as these will be less space consuming than the space taken in the database.

The issue I am having is with stripping the img src tags etc from the screenshot and successfully saving the data into an image file that can be opened correctly.

The pasted screenshot data is inserted into the database as below:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,_BASE_64_DATA_HERE"><br>
```

Any ideas, when posting this data, on how to strip the unnecessary items and just leave the base64 data, creating a saved PNG image?

Currently I have this, which is not quite working for me, just creating an image that can't be opened:

```
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($screenshot);
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $screenshot));

file_put_contents('screenshots/screens.png', $data);
```

The `$screenshot` is the pasted data.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest removing the `^` start of string anchor and use `preg_match` with the use of `\K` to truncate all before the image Base64 data that will be captured with `[^"<]*` pattern - 0 or more characters other than `"` and `<` (probably, it can even be reduced to `[^"]*`):

```
preg_match('#data:image/\w+;base64,\K[^"<]*#i', '<img src="data:image/png;base64,_BASE_64_DATA_HERE"><br>', $match);
echo $match[0]; // => _BASE_64_DATA_HERE
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/B6MaML)

Comment: Thanks for this, strips as requested. I have just tried using this to create a PNG however the image that is created is still not able to be opened accurately. How might this become achievable?

Comment: I have no idea what string you pass in $screenshot, and I cannot tell you how to recreate the image. If correct string data is saved in the db, I think it is not in scope of the current question.

Comment: <img src="data:image/png;base64,_BASE_64_DATA_HERE"><br>  is the value of $screenshot and is what is saved into the database. I'd like to use the base64 data from this to form the image, saving it in PNG form rather than saving inside a database.

Comment: If `_BASE_64_DATA_HERE` does not contain a `"`, the negated character class `[^"<]*` with `*` quantifier is sure to extract correct substring. I have no idea what you need to do further. If it is not related to regex, and if the regex works, I think you need to log another question and finalize this one.